# What does "ans += n << count" mean?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

```
// Function for multiplication 
int multiply(int n, int m) 
{   
    int ans = 0, count = 0; 
    while (m) 
    { 
        if (m % 2 == 1)               
            ans += n << count; 

        // increment of place value (count) 
        count++; 
        m /= 2; 
    } 
    return ans; 
}
```

What does that expression mean? How to rewrite this expression in a more beginner friendly form?

Comment: To make it more beginner friendly, just do one operation per line. Store the result of `n << count` in a temporary variable and them `+=` it to `ans`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are bitwise shift (bit-shift) operators and how do they work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141525/what-are-bitwise-shift-bit-shift-operators-and-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 3):

The expression `ans += n << count;` means the same as the following:

```
int n_shifted = n << count;  /* bitshift n to the left by count bits */
ans = ans + n_shifted;       /* add n_shifted to ans */
```

Answer (score 1):

it bitshifts `n` left by `count` then adds it to `ans`

```
n << 1  =   n * 2
n << 2  =   n * 4
n << 3  =   n * 8
n << 4  =   n * 16
```

etc